# Inefficient CoreData IN Query

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, core-data, nspredicate

I've got what should be a pretty simple CoreData setup that looks like this:

```
Track {
    NSSet *artists;
    NSSet *genres;
}

Artist {
    NSSet *tracks;
}

Genre {
    NSSet *tracks;
}
```

So the idea here is, a `Track` can have multiple `Genre`s and `Artist`s. There is an inverse relationship back to `Track` in both cases.

I'm trying to get a list of `Artist`s which have at least one `Track` of a given `Genre`. I'm using the following predicate: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tracks in %@", genre.tracks]`.

Most of the time this is fast, but sometimes I have a `Genre` with 10k+ `Tracks`. This generates a SQL query with 10k+ variables... this takes a long time to run.

I've tried all kinds of things to avoid this including:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %@ in tracks", genre.tracks]
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN SUBQUERY(tracks, $t, %@ IN $t.genres)", genre]
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(tracks, $t, %@ IN $t.genres).@count > 0)", genre];
```

And probably some more that I've forgotten. Each of these compiles, but returns no `Artist` objects.

What can I do to improve upon the efficiency of the IN query I started with (which works)?

Comment: What about `(SUBQUERY(tracks, $t, ANY t.genres = %@).@count > 0)", genre` ?

Comment: We have a winner!! Thanks, I spent hours without trying that particular combination of magic. If you enter that as a proper reply I'll happily mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(SUBQUERY(tracks, $t, ANY t.genres = %@).@count > 0)", genre]
```

which gives the same result as your original predicate, but avoids to build a query with many parameters.